# Cannot stop hotspot from loading which prevents wifi from auto loading

Tags: wi-fi, android-10

I have an Android head unit, which has hot spot details inserted, which I can't delete or remove with factory reset. I want to have my wifi to auto load on boot, but the hot spot prevents this from happening.
What can I do to disable the hot spot permanently or have it turn off after it starts and auto start my head units wifi.
It's a Chinese HU, Android 10

Thanks

Comment: Can you load an app from Play Store or sideload it? If yes, try an automation app such as MacroDroid or Tasker or Automate and use any of them to wait for boot completion, detect hostspot is active, then enable Wifi (which would turn off hotpost automatically).

Comment: Play Store works fine, I'll give them a go.Which would be the easiest to use?

Comment: Try Macrodroid.